# how could I publish multiple random messages for each mqtt client in a random way not sequentially to the same broker using python client?

Tags: python, multithreading, mqtt

This is my python client code for publishing messages of 10 publishers, I want every publisher to send multiple messages not sequentially for example client 1 can publish a message then client 5 then client 1 can send again another message then client 9, and so on.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import os
import random

#variables
MQTT_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
MQTT_PORT = 1883
MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 5
MQTT_TOPIC = "sampleTopic"
MQTT_MSG = "Hello MQTT"
publishers = []
num_publishers = 10


#Callback Functions
def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print("log: "+buf)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0 :
        print("connected OK"+str(client))
        mqttc.publish(MQTT_TOPIC,MQTT_MSG)
    else:
        print("Bad connection returned code = ",rc)

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0):
    print("Disconnected result code " +str(rc))

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    topic = msg.topic
    m_decode = str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
    print("message received", m_decode)
       
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("Message Published...")
    time.sleep(random.randint(3,9))# sleep for 10 seconds before next call
    
for i in range(num_publishers):
    #Initiate MQTT Client
    id = "Publisher "+str(i)
    client = mqtt.Client(id)
    publishers.append(client)
        
try:

    for mqttc in publishers:

        #Binding Callback Functions
        mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
        mqttc.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
        mqttc.on_message = on_message
        mqttc.on_publish = on_publish
        # mqttc.on_log = on_log

        #connect with MQTT broker
        mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST,MQTT_PORT,MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)

        #loop network
        mqttc.loop_start()
        time.sleep(0.5)

    while True:
        pass

except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print("interrupted by keyboard")

os._exit(0)
```

I tried paho.mqtt.publish.multiple() but it did not work for my requirements.

Comment: If you want the multiple publishers to behave nearly randomly then you will need to run them on separate threads and have them wait random pause length between publishing messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not know how to separate between messages of single client could you tell me how could I edit the client code to do that?

Comment: What research into writing multi-threaded Python apps have you done?